# Using Groovy Library in Grails and getting 'No suitable ClassLoader found for grab'

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm playing around with Grails/Groovy and have some straight Groovy code working that utilizes groovy-wslite. That code starts as such

**send-request.groovy**

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='1.1.0')
import wslite.soap.*
```

When I implement that into my Grails code and view the controller/action I get this

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI: /FormProj/hello/trigger
Class: java.lang.RuntimeException
Message: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab
```

And here's the code in it's current state (I've tried a LOT of different things)

**HelloController.groovy**

```
package com.demo
import groovy.grape.Grape

class HelloController {

    def index() { }

    def sayHi() {
        return [
            greeting : "Hi there, ${ params.name }"
        ]
    }

    def trigger() {
        Grape.grab(group:'com.github.groovy-wslite', module:'groovy-wslite', version:'1.1.0')
        …
    }
}
```

As I'm sure you notice I'm very green with Grails/Groovy and really all things Java.  I do know there is a wslite plugin for Grails, but surely this can work too right?

Grails: 2.3.8

Groovy: 2.2.2

**UPDATE**

---

Based on Ian Robert's advice I have updated my `BuildConfig` file by adding this line to the `dependencies` block

```
compile 'com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.0'
```

And updated my controller to look like this

**HelloController.groovy**

```
package ws.thejspot
import wslite.soap.*

class HelloController {

    def index() { }

    def sayHi() {
        return [
            greeting : "Hi there, ${ params.name }"
        ]
    }

    def trigger() {
        def client = new SOAPClient('URL')
    }
}
```

Unfortunately now the IDE, GGTS, shows an error in the controller 'unable to resolve class SOAPClient'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than trying to download the dependencies with `@Grab`, you should use the standard Grails dependency mechanism - edit `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy` and look for the `grails.project.dependency.resolution` closure.  Inside that, in the `dependencies` block you should add

```
compile 'com.github.groovy-wslite:groovy-wslite:1.1.0'
```

and remove anything Grape-related from the controller, leaving just the `import wslite.soap.*`

You will probably need to run

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

at least once to ensure that Grails picks up your change to `BuildConfig` - it deliberately doesn't do a full dependency resolve every time you compile, so as not to slow down the build too much, so you need to tell it to refresh when you know it needs to.

Comment: Hi Ian, so I've added the line you mentioned to the BuildConfig file, and removed all Grape-related items from the controller.  The next line in the method, which works in my stand-alone groovy code, is def client = new SOAPClient('URL'), but now the IDE flags an error 'unable to resolve class SOAPClient'

Comment: @dscl you still need the `import`, just not the `@Grab`

Comment: sorry I actually didn't mention that I do have that in there.  So to recap I added the compile line to BuildConfig and my controller now has the import wslite.soap.* at the top, but inside my class method the IDE still warns me at that line that it's unable to resolve class SOAPClient.  Is this a false positive maybe?

Comment: @dscl that should be OK now, when I get random unexplained things like this from my IDE I find a clean rebuild of the project usually fixes it.

Comment: Talk about frustrating I couldn't get a clean to work so I built a brand new project added the dependency, created a controller, added the import, added the line def client = new SOAPClient('URL') and still get the same error

Comment: @dscl if you haven't already then try "`grails compile --refresh-dependencies`" to make sure it's noticed the change to `BuildConfig`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59744/discussion-between-dscl-and-ian-roberts).

Comment: I just tried this myself with a new project (Grails 2.2.3, Java 7u67, Eclipse Juno with GGTS plugins), and doing "refresh dependencies" followed by refreshing the project was enough to get it to recognise `new SOAPClient('http://example.com')`

Comment: After much trying I did get it to work like this `def client = new wslite.soap.SOAPClient('URL')`